# Is there a way to find all the data extensions that make use of a particular data relationship?

Tags: marketing-cloud, metadata-relationship

I would like to see a list of all data extensions (standard and filtered) that are using a specific data relationship. I thought there might be a column in data extensions that displays data relationships in use by data extension but it seems not.